# Rails model containing list of integers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

How can I have a list of integers as an attribute of a Rails model? I've tried Googling, but nothing comes up. Do I really have to create a seperate model just to hold the integer and then use a has_many relation?

What if I want to have multiple lists in the model? Do I create a seperate model for each list?

What I'm trying to do is create models to represent the state of a board game called Ra. The variables I came up with are

```
Game
    epoch - int
    currentturn - int
    auctionturn - int
    ratrack - int
    centralsun  - int
    auctiontrack - list[int]
    playerdata - list[playerdata]

PlayerData
    name - string
    suns - list[int]
    nextsuns - list[int]
    gods - int
    pharohs - int
    niles - int
    floods - int
    gold - int
    civilization - list[int]
    monuments - list[int]
    fame - int
```

But I'm not sure how to implement this. Also, does anyone have suggestions to improve the design?

Comment: if u r using mongoid, u can save the array of integers. for active_record, u cant save the array. if u dont wanna create a new model, u can save the integers as a string by joining the integers. eg "1,2,3,4". u can override the attr_accessor for the field to give u a array of ints and convert it to string before saving but this approach is a hack. i think, u should create a general model and define its relationship as belongs_to polymorphic(may belong to playerdata or game).

Comment: @surase How can I save an array in Mongoid?

Comment: field: :some_field, type: Array, default: []

Answer (score 2):

You can store any object in a a database field using `serialize`:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize

Support for actual array objects (in PostGres, at least) is going to be added in Rails 4, by the way:
 http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/09/18/rails-4-sneak-peek-postgresql-array-support.html